# How do I define a type for both property name and value in an object when using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object in which both the properies and values correspond to their respective types:

```js
type Car = "toyota" | "mazda" | "suzuki" | "porsche";
type Color = "white" | "black" | "yellow" | "red";
const cars = {
    toyota: "red",
    porsche: "white",
};
```

I know I can assign a type to the property like so:

```js
const cars: {
    [key in Car]: string;
  } = {
    toyota: "red",
    porsche: "white",
};
```

This works but I would like the value to only be of type Color. The following does not work:

```js
const cars: {
    [key in Car]: [key in Color];
  } = {
    toyota: "red",
    porsche: "white",
};
```

Why doesn't the above code work, and how may I define a type for both property name and value?

Comment: Replace `[key in Color]` with `Color`?

Comment: Can you not update the type to this? 

`Partial<Record<Car, Color>`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you. That worked! But how come I have to use `[key in Car]` for the property name while the value can simply be written of as `Color`?

Comment: It seems using the Record utility is even more straighforward: `Record<Car, Color>`

Comment: Yes it is, because the object `cars` does not contain all the keys and values from `Car` and `Color`.  But remember to use `Partial<>`

Comment: @codemax Thank you for the comment! I undestand now. Just using `Record<>` will force the type to have all the property names (keys) in Car, while wrapping it in `Partial<>` will require at least one key in Car, but make it optional to have more than one.